# Cancel style button not working in actionsheet of Ipad

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to implement actionsheet in ipad with the help of popoverPresentationController.everything is working fine but i am facing one problem that Cancel
style button is not coming in the actionsheet.
here is my code for refernece

````
   @IBAction func logoutAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "do you want to logout", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                   let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                       Singleton.sharedInstance.logoutButtonAction()
                       logEvent(label: "user_log_out")
                   })
                   let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                       self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                   })
                  alertController.addAction(yesAction)
                   alertController.addAction(noAction)
                   alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self?.view
            alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
                 /*  if let presenter = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
                       presenter.sourceView = self!.logoutButton
                       presenter.sourceRect = self!.logoutButton.bounds
                      }*/
                  
                  self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               })
       
    }
    ```
````

Comment: It's the new normal. Change it to .destructive if you want the button.

Comment: Thanks,I thought of using the same,but since I am using only two button so I will use alert instead of actionsheet.